# Moving div to the right of a floated element, but under two others

Tags: html, css, xhtml, width

This is a CSS question that's driving me up the wall. Below is the code I currently have, and I want the description text to be to the right of the blue box (i.e. under the title), but for it to continue over, under the 'button'. I've tried various combinations, but they all either start at the current position or underneath the title but indented by its width.

Any help greatly appreciated

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { background-color: #fff; color: white; }
            .outer { width: 850px; height: 400px; background-color: #000; }
            .logo {float: left; width:150px;height:150px;background-color: #00f;}
            .button {float: right; height: 60px; width: 80px; background-color: #f00; }
            .title { font-size: 60px; float:left;}
            .desc {clear:both;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="logo">oo</div>
                <div>
                    <div class="title">Title</div>
                    <div class="button">button</div>
                    <div class="desc">description text description text description text description text description text description text description text description text description text description text description text description text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Example]

The text should be where the white box is in the image above.

Comment: Can you draw a simple picture showing what you want?

Comment: Okay, edited to show what I mean :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that should be very simple eh? Just float it to the left and give it a width...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wYQmd/)

CSS

```
.desc {
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: (And thanks to the other person who suggested inline-block for the title, but then deleted before I had chance to thank!)